# Browser back button show modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have 3 asp.net pages. 
Clicking on PAGE 1 link navigates to Page 2 on Modal Popup.
Clicking on PAGE 2 link closes Modal popup and navigates to PAGE 3 on Main window.
I would like to go back to Modal popup(PAGE 2) when the Browser back button clicked while I am on PAGE 3. Right now it navigates to PAGE 1 when Browser back button clicked.
Could you please let me know if there are any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript cookie to check if the modal has been opened before.

Note: I have tested this code locally on my machine and a lot of script limitations ocurs. You can read about JS cookie and test a simillar example online at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

```
<body onload="checkModal()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openModal(){
            document.cookie = 'modalopened=true';
            alert('Modal page'); // Open your modal here
        }

        function checkModal()
        {
            if (document.cookie == 'modalopened=true')
            {    
                openModal();
                document.cookie = '';
            }
        }
    </script>

    <input type="button" onclick="openModal()" value="Open">
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Go to another page and come back here.</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This One

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function goBack() 
{
 window.history.go(-1)
 }
</script>
 <a href="#" id="btnreturnback" runat="server" onclick="javascript:goBack();return false;"></a>
```